# Why was this edit correcting outdated links rejected?

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits, specific-edit

Back in 2009, I wrote [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1316206/2988). This answer contained some links to project pages, homepages, etc. that no longer exist or have moved.

A helpful editor [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24403879) which fixes those links. However, that edit was rejected as "deviates from the original intent" and "intended as a comment".

Now, as the original author of that answer, I can assure you that providing dead links was most certainly *not* the original intent. And likewise, I don't see anything wrong with fixing those links instead of writing a comment prompting me to fix those links. Isn't that *exactly* what editing is for?

I now [approved the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1316206/revisions), but I don't understand why I had to do that in the first place. What was wrong with the original edit that lead to its rejection?

Comment: I can only guess that one editor thought that the links supplied were wrong, hence it "deviates from intent", the other thought that even if they were correct it shouldn't have been an edit but a comment to the effect of "hey link X is now Y". I disagree with both of these reasons but it's my best guess why the reviewers made those choices.

Comment: Whenever I get a 'fixed broken link' type edit to review, I generally hit the "Skip" button! Reason: unless it's a topic I am familiar with, how else can I check that the new link has the same 'intent' as the original (which now I can't check, obviously)? But I agree that to outright "Reject" is often wrong.

Comment: @Adrian I direct your attention to the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I agree with you.  Both of those edit rejections were clearly wrong.

It is reasonable to assume that the author did not intend the link to be broken, so any fixing of broken links does not automatically conflict with the author's intent.  The only situation where it *might* conflict is if the new link points to a totally different document, page, project or whatever.  Even then it does not *necessarily* conflict.

The other rejection reason is nonsense.  If the link is broken and it can be fixed, then it should be fixed in the Question, not in a comment.

I think that the edit should be nominated as an audit for the edit review queue.

Comment: Upvoted for general sensibleness and accepted for the last paragraph / sentence.

Comment: As far as I know, audits are chosen automatically based on reactions to the post (universally positive or negative feedback, typically). I don't think there's a way to manually add one.